# Show that $f$ is constant on each sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered at the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi everyone this is a past exam question that I am studying as I go through my class that I am having trouble with, the full question is this:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and suppose that

$$ \nabla f(\textbf{x}) = g(\textbf{x})\textbf{x} $$ for all $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ where $g: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is a function. Show that $f$ is constant on each sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered at $(0,0,0)$. i.e. show that if $\textbf{a}$, $\textbf{b}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\|\textbf{a}\| = \|\textbf{b}\|$ then $f(\textbf{a}) = f(\textbf{b})$.

I'm stuck on this question and not sure which direction to take. I'm really just throwing ideas around.

I do know that the gradient vector at $\textbf{a}$ is perpendicular to all the tangent lines to the level set $f^{-1}(c)$ at $\textbf{a}$.

Then letting $\textbf{x} = h(t) = (h_{1}(t), h_{2}(t), h_{3}(t))$ with $h(0)= \textbf{a}$.

I have $f(h(\textbf{0}))=c$. Then taking derivatives:

$$\frac{d}{dt}f(h(\textbf{0})) = \frac{d}{dt} c = 0$$

$$h'(0) \cdot \bigtriangledown f(h(\textbf{0})) = 0$$

Substituting in for $f(h(\textbf{0}))$ yields

$$h'(0) \cdot g(\textbf{a})\textbf{a} = 0$$

Now i'm really not sure where to go from here, how relate the magnitude of $\textbf{a}$ or $\textbf{b}$ to the question (do i need to parametrise?) I would really appreciate some guidance with this question.

Comment: As written, the claim is false.  Let $g(x)$ be the function that returns the first coordinate of $x$.  Then $g(x)x$ is differentiable and always radially directed, except on the $y$-$z$ plane where it is zero, so is not radially directed (it's still differentiable there).  $f$ isn't constant on *any* sphere of positive radius.  Are you sure there isn't an additional condition?

Comment: @EricTowers - Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by let $g(x)$ be the function that returns the first coordinate of $x$. The question states the $g(x)$ is $f:R^3 \rightarrow R$?

Comment: The problem does not say this about $g$.  The problem only requires that $g$ is a function with domain $\mathbb{R}^3$ and range $\mathbb{R}$.  There are no further restrictions (stated) on $g$.  The function $g((x_1,x_2,x_3)) \mapsto x_1$ certainly meets this prescription.

Comment: But then what does $g(\textbf{x})\textbf{x}$ mean? $\textbf{x}$ is a vector. My understanding is that $g(\textbf{x})$ just returns a constant, multiplied to the vector $\textbf{x}$. I checked the question, and I haven't missed anything.

Comment: Yes.  "$g(x)x$" is the vector in the direction of $x$ with magnitude $g(x)|x|$.  There is nothing in the above requiring that $g(x)$ is constant for all $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I appreciate your help, but I am still not understanding. The way I read the question is that the gradient vector at any point is a scalar multiple of the vector giving that point. Since $g(\textbf{x})$ is from $R^3 \rightarrow R$, so it just returns a number/constant right? What else could it return? What could the question be missing?

Comment: $g(x)$ returns a scalar.  That scalar can be different for every $x$.  In fact it would be just as good to write $\nabla f(x) = \langle\text{a randomly selected number for each }x\rangle x$ and then hope that this somehow maintains spherical symmetry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13702/discussion-between-mathstudent-and-eric-towers)

Comment: Can't.  Heading to bed.  Good luck.

Comment: You wish to prove that $f$ is a radially symmetric function, namely a function that depends only on $r=\|x\|$: $f(x)=\tilde{f}(r)$. But for such a function (assuming differentiability) $\nabla f(x)=\tilde{f}'(r)r$ as you can easily check by the chain rule. So you have a necessary condition that looks rather different than your assumption on $g$.

Comment: @EricTowers  your proposed counterexample does not work.  With this choice of $g$,  $g(x)x$ is not the gradient of a function.

Comment: @Siminore I understand your first two sentences, so then I would have $\tilde{f}'(r)r = g(\textbf{x})\textbf{x}$. So then what does this mean? Could you elaborate a little further for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\gamma(0) = a$ and $\gamma(1) = b$, and with $|\gamma(t)| = r = |a|=|b|$ for all $t$, i.e.  $\gamma$ lies entirely on the sphere of radius $r= |a|=|b|$ centered at the origin.

I want to show that $(f \circ \gamma): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a constant function. One way to do this is to show that its derivative is always $0$.

$\begin{align*}(f \circ \gamma)'(t) &= \nabla f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \text{ by the chain rule} \\
&=g(\gamma(t))\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t)\\
&=0
\end{align*}$

The last equality follows since $\gamma(t)$ is a radial vector and $\gamma'(t)$ is a tangent vector to the sphere. Another way to see this is to use the chain rule again:

Let $R(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$.  Then $R(\gamma(t)) = r$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.  By the chain rule,
$$
\nabla R(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t) = 0
$$

But by a computation, $\nabla R (x,y,z)= 2\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$.  In other words $\nabla R (v) = 2v$  So we have

$$
2\gamma(t)\cdot \gamma'(t)=0
$$

Thus $(f \circ \gamma)'(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, so $(f \circ \gamma)$ is constant.  So $f(a) = f(b)$.  Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary points on the sphere of radius $r$, we have that $f$ is constant on any sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: sorry did you mean that $\gamma (t)$ is perpendicular to the sphere? Also, (sorry this might be a dumb question, but why do you have that $\gamma$ has domain [0,1]? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Paths usually have domain $[0,1]$, but this is convention:  they have to start and end somewhere!  $\gamma{t}$ is a point on the sphere, or a vector from the origin to the sphere depending on how you look at it.  As a vector it is always perpendicular to tangent vectors to the sphere (a radial line to a sphere is perpendicular to the tangent plane at that point)

Comment: Thanks, so just to clarify, in your answer, where you have '$\gamma '(t)$ is perpendicular to the sphere', you actually meant '$\gamma (t)$ is perpendicular to the sphere' Is that correct? Also, where you have $f:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ that is analogous to $f: R^3 \rightarrow R$?

Comment: Correct, sorry.

Comment: I typed this answer as it took form in my mind, but I think it might be clearer if I rework it.  Going to make a major edit.

Comment: @mathstudent What do you not like about this answer exactly?

Comment: I just wanted to see if there were additional ways to answer the question - just to expand my intuitive understanding. Your answer is very good though, thank you.

Comment: You said you wanted an answer with more rigor.  I do not see what is not rigorous about my proof.  The only thing (maybe) is that $\gamma(t)$ is perpendicular to $\gamma'(t)$.  The proof of this is just another application of the chain rule.  Would you like me to put that in?

Comment: Yes that would be good. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Steven, I do have a question: While I see clearly that you have demonstrated that if two vectors are of the same length then, we do indeed get a constant function, but is this the same as showing $f(a)=f(b)$? Could it be that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ both given constants, but different constants?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea:

If $|\mathbf{a}| = |\mathbf{b}|$, pick a path $\gamma$ lying entirely within the sphere of that common radius connecting $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{b}) - f(\mathbf{a}) &= \int_\gamma \nabla f \cdot \vec{dr}\\
&=\int_\gamma g(x)\vec{x}\cdot \vec{dr}
\end{align*}$

You need to conclude that this integral is $0$.  Can you see why it is?

Comment: We actually haven't gone into the integration part of the course yet, so I'll have to look ahead a bit..is there a way to do it using differentiation? Thanks.